# OpenGLで葉っぱの3Dモデリングをする手順

Tags: opengl

大学の課題で、こちらの論文を元に葉っぱの葉脈を描画するということをしたいのですがつまづいております
http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/venation.sig2005.pdf

まずは葉っぱの3Dモデリングを完成させてから、葉脈をその上で描画するという手順で考えているのですが、このアプローチは正しいでしょうか？

また、OpenGLはド素人ですので、何から始めていいやら分かりません。
抽象的な質問で申し訳ありませんが、3Dモデリングするにあたってアドバイスや、参考になるサイト、書籍などありましたら教えてください。

Comment: 課題を出された教諭に聞いたり、教科書を理解するのが早い気がしますが...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

論文はざっと見ただけですが、平面上の話ですよね? でしたら3Dモデルはひとまず忘れて、平面上に葉脈のパターンを作るのが先決だと思いますがいかがでしょう。論文のFig.9やFig.13のような画を描くのを目標にします。

それだけなら、OpenGLは難しいことを考えずに単に「2D平面に座標を指定して点や線を描けるもの」だと思っておけば良いです。画を出すための「オマジナイ」が多少ありますが、座標を動かさないのなら適当な入門書のサンプルを参考にして描画部分だけ変えればいけます。例えばOpenGL Programming GuideのExample 1-1が2Dの正方形を描いているので、まずそれを動かしてから、glBeginとglEndの間を適当に変えてゆきます。後は2D平面で正しい座標を計算できさえすれば画が出てくるのでOpenGLのことは忘れても構いません。(カメラを動かしたりすると、ちょっとした計算間違いで画が出てこなくて最初のうちは悩むんですが)。

葉脈の画が2Dで描けたら、それをテクスチャとして取得して3D空間に配置したポリゴンに貼り込むことになります。でも課題の主題はそれ以前のところにあるような印象を受けますね。

Answer (score 1):

手続き的に（計算で）葉っぱぽい形状とテクスチャーを作りたいって事ですよね？
的確に答えられる人がここを見ている可能性はとてつもなく低いので、課題を出した教授に聞くのが一番早いと思います。
普通何のヒントもなしにこういう課題は出さないと思うのですが。